# WSO2 IS soap service call for listing users from secondary user store - Troubles with Pagination and Retrieving claim values on user search

Tags: web-services, soap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have to develop a user directory page using WSO2 SOAP Service API's with following features:

1. Pagination.
2. Listing Users along with its claim values (Given name/ Display name, phone & email).

I am trying to use the below mentioned WSO2 SOAP Services.

1. /services/UserAdmin?wsdl
2. /services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl

I am facing troubles with respect to pagination and listing users with its claims. My Questions are:

1. Is there any WSO2 IS SOAP Service which has inbuilt Pagination to list all the users?
2. Is there any WSO2 IS SOAP Service to list uers along with its claim values?

Thanks in advance